# How do you achieve an efficiency of more than 1 bit per Hertz?

Tags: communication, physics

I believe this is also known as spectral efficiency - apparently it's possible for us to transmit more than one bit per Hertz.

But to my layman mind I imagine a Hertz being only capable of representing a single bit, on or off. Perhaps that's just because I'm visualising a square wave, and there's some way to cram more data in than that if you can get something more complex than a square wave to the other side clean enough.

Could someone explain this in detail, touching on what the concept is called and some methods used commonly such as in the 802.11 specification.

Comment: actually, you can get 2 bps per Hz of bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

One way is for instance amplitude modulation. Imagine a system where the receiving end of a transmission pair is aligned and setup in such a way that the received waveform is always exactly proportionate to the sent waveform. The sending party now sends a carrier wave and modulates its amplitude at 1Hz, but it can send many different levels which can all be distinguished by the receiving end.

For instance, you can encode 4096 different levels even though the bandwidth is just one Hz. Each state contains 12 bits of information. Bandwidth is 1Hz. Voila.

Of course, in any real-world application there is noise, interference, not to mention the receiver is often moving with respect to the transmitter. It is hard to distinguish so many different signalling levels. How much *can* be distinguished is what we call signal-to-noise ratio (SNR), and this is why people say that with high enough SNR you can transmit more than 1 bit per Hz of bandwidth.

Besides amplitude modulation, phase modulation (using two carriers) is also used to transmit information. The arbitrary combination of these methods is called QAM or quadrature amplitude modulation. For instance, QAM-2048 is what my glass fiber internet connection uses, which means that each Hz of the carrier can convey 2048 levels or 11 bits of information.

Comment: "you can encode 4096 different levels even though the bandwidth is just one Hz" -- I don't think that's correct. A bandwidth of 1Hz refers to a *pure sine wave* of that frequency. Anything you modulate onto that 1Hz sine wave will add other frequencies to the signal, and anything above 1Hz modulated onto the sine will increase the signal bandwidth needed beyond 1Hz.

Comment: @HannoBinder  1Hz pure sine wave has zero bandwidth, provided it has existed forever and will exist forever (at the identical amplitude). Obviously it is incapable of carrying any information.

Comment: @HannoBinder: Given any discrete sequence of N desired voltages, one may construct a waveform such that discrete samples taken at one-second intervals from a particular reference time will yield that sequence, without the signal needing to contain any spectral component above 0.5Hz.  The signal won't just contain 0Hz and 0.5Hz, but other multiples of 1/N between 0Hz and 0.5Hz as well.  It need not, however, contain anything above 0.5Hz.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Yes, a pure sine wave has a *data* bandwidth of 0 bps. However, the *signal* bandwidth still is 1Hz. To carry that wave the medium must support at least that *signal* bandwidth of 1Hz.

Comment: @supercat Are you saying that amplitude modulation does not increase a signal bandwidth beyond the carrier frequency? - Consider the frequency sidebands which occur, see for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation#Spectrum .

Comment: @HannoBinder: Amplitude modulation with a signal that has no frequency components over F hertz will not expand the bandwidth by more than F hertz on either side.

Comment: Exactly. Modulating, for instance, 0.5Hz onto a 1Hz carrier yields 1.5Hz signal bandwith.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OOK (on-off keying) then the baseband bandwidth required is 1/2 of the data rate.  1 Mbit/sec requires DC to 500 kHz of bandwidth (think about it: the highest frequency component will be generated when you send 01010101, and that frequency is 1/2 of the data rate).

Other modulation formats have a higher information density.  Multilevel coding such as PAM-4 (pulse amplitude modulation) can transfer more bits at the same time.  In communications systems, there are two rates: the bit rate and the symbol rate.  If you're using on-off keying, the symbols are 'off' and 'on' and each represent one bit state, so each symbol represents one bit and the bit rate and symbol rate are the same.  When you switch to something like PAM-4, there are four different levels to choose from and as a result each level can encode 2 bits.  This means that the data rate will be double the symbol rate.  Modulation formats like QAM (quadrature amplitude modulation) add phase as a component as well, allowing for even more complicated symbols.  However, there is a tradeoff: more signal levels means the receiver has a harder time figuring out which level was transmitted due to the signal being mixed with noise.  This puts a limit on how complex the symbols are as there has to be a good enough SNR for the system to be usable.

When you use OOK, the bandwidth required is equal to the data rate (e.g. 1 bit per Hz) because when you AM modulate a carrier with a message, you get two sidebands so the signal occupies the frequency range fc+fm to fc-fm.  With PAM-4, the symbol rate is the same, so the bandwidth required is the same.  However, the bit rate is doubled, so the result is 2 bits per Hz.  QAM-64 has 64 different amplitude and phase shift combinations, representing 6 data bits - yielding 6 bits per Hz.

In the study of information theory, there is something called the Shannon-Hartley theorem that indicates the maximum amount of data that can be transmitted through a given bandwith with a given SNR:

C = B log2 (1 + S/N)

where C is the capacity in bits per second, B is the bandwidth in Hz, S is the signal power in watts, and N is the noise power in watts.  This indicates the best possible data rate that you can successfully transmit in a given bandwidth under a given SNR.

Answer (score 1):

Let's design a hypothetical modulation scheme. As a first requirement, we want it to be very narrow-band, but we don't care about speed. This means we can't change any parameter of the carrier (phase, amplitude) very quickly, otherwise we would introduce harmonics which would increase our bandwidth.

So, let's say our modulation scheme is thus: we transmit a 1000 Hz carrier. Each night at midnight we sample the amplitude of this carrier to obtain the received data. If the amplitude is greater than 0.5, it's a "1". If it's less, it's a "0". Meanwhile, the transmitter changes the amplitude gradually over the course of the day towards its target at midnight.

$$\begin{align}
0 \le\ &a < 0.5 &: 0 \\
0.5 \le\ &a < 1 &: 1
\end{align}$$

This 1000 Hz carrier, being modulated at the rate of 1 symbol per day, has a *very* narrow bandwidth, but also the bit rate is absurdly slow: 1 bit per day.

We can improve on this. What if each symbol, instead of representing one bit, represents two bits? Now each symbol has *four* possible values:

$$\begin{align}
0 \le\ &a < 0.25 &: 00 \\
0.25 \le\ &a < 0.5 &: 01 \\
0.5 \le\ &a < 0.75 &: 10 \\
0.75 \le\ &a < 1 &: 11
\end{align}$$

We are still sending symbols at 1 per day, so the carrier isn't being modulated any faster, so bandwidth isn't any greater. However, we get twice the bits, so while our [symbol rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_rate) is 1 per day, our [bit rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate) is 2 per day.

Now you can see where this is going: we can define arbitrarily many bits per symbol, so we can make the bit rate arbitrarily high. The only trouble is that noise adds a bit of random variation to our amplitude, so the odds of an error become greater. The [Shannon-Hartley theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) is one way to model how much data can be crammed into a limited bandwidth at a given signal-to-noise ratio.